Simple doorbell circuit using transistors
This is a circuit diagram for constructing a simple doorbell circuit using transistors.
Can anyone see a fault in the circuit? I've tried it on a breadboard and the circuit works with the buzzer as a replacement for the speaker, but when I try it with the speaker, it does not work. The speaker that I tried was 8 Ω and 0.5 W.

Here's the link for reference.

Welcome.  Do you have a scope?  If so, please show the voltage at Q3 collector for the case with buzzer, and the case with speaker as load.  What is the supply - is it a 9V battery?  What is the battery voltage when the speaker is the load - it could be dropping too low.

Hello, thank you for commenting! I tried with multimeter, when I pressed the button with the speaker connected, the voltage of the collector of Q3 dropped from 5.71 V to 2.00 V. If the buzzer is connected the voltage of the collector Q3 dropped from 5.6 V to 0.04 V. Also, yes I'm using a 9V battery.

What was the battery voltage (across its terminals) with (a) buzzer load, with switch S1 off and on, and (b) speaker load, for S1 off and on?

These are the voltages (I replaced the battery since the other one is only getting 6V from the reading)
a) Buzzer load:
S1 OFF - 9V
S1 ON - 6.55 V
a) Speaker load:
S1 OFF - 9V
S1 ON - 4.58 V

The reading of 4.58V when the load is a speaker, and S1 pushed (closed), is telling me that the battery is being overloaded.   Even the buzzer load is causing overload.   You only have two options available:  1. Find a bigger battery or power supply that can deliver the load current, or 2. Reduce the load current of your circuit.  You can try out option 2 by replacing R6 (27Ω) with a larger resistor, say, 220Ω, and see how that goes.  The buzzer may not work, and the speaker may be very faint, but at least you won't over load the battery.

@MondeAlbevar I agree you should increase the 27 Ohm resistor by a factor of 10. A piezo (buzzer) is net-capacitive. A speaker is net-inductive. They have opposite reactance sign. There is a reactive magnitude difference, as well as sign. I'm not surprised it may behave somewhat differently in two different load-type cases. There are also simpler topologies that likely can handle both kinds of loads. I know because I've done it. But I'd need to get out some old notebooks to refresh my memory. I may remember enough but I wouldn't write without getting out a board first and verifying.

Thank you for your replies, I have tried increasing the resistor's value by 220Ω, the buzzer is still working and the changes that it made is with the sound, the sound it gave after clicking the switch became longer. Tried it out with the speaker too, still no luck. I have 4 speakers that I bought and tried with the circuit and they all don't produce sound.

If you have four speakers on hand, here is an idea you can try: connect them all in series, then connect them to your original circuit.  Re-test, including the battery voltage measurements with speaker load, for S1 off and S1 on.  You might get the sound you need.  Failing that, test your original circuit with a power supply capable of delivering at least 0.5A.

**Do you have a scope? If so, please show the voltage at Q3 collector for the case with buzzer, and the case with speaker as load. **

These common "multivibrator" circuits have a serious problem: startup. The transistors are biased into saturation, and if the oscillations ever stop - say due to a temporarily shorted output of the oscillator - they won't restart.
Instead, the transistors should be biased to have well-defined gain. Below, Q1 and Q2 operate at DC gain of 1, but very high AC gain (>10). They amplify their own noise, thus the oscillations will always start up. Q1 and Q2 can never be permanently saturated. They only saturate on transitions of their inputs.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The first block from the left is the oscillator (Q1, Q2). It is followed by a rectangular wave former (Q3) with volume adjust (VR1). Q4..Q7 are a push-pull final stage.
The circuit can push much more power into the speaker than the output transistor and a small speaker can handle - ensure that VR1 is adjusted down as necessary.
At mid-point volume setting, the waveforms at points A, B and OUT look as follows:


First, try moving C3, the 33uF capacitor, to be directly attached to the 9V battery. Putting C3 on the switched side may start the circuit up slowly, preventing oscillator startup.
An excellent article on circuits like yours can be found at the Nuts-And-Volts Bipolar Transistor Cookbook, Part 6, one section of some excellent teaching.
The following excerpt may answer your question directly:

I did not try the above circuit yet, but rather just played around with yours, which seemed to work just fine. You may want to test your transistors and diodes, your battery, etc -- all the basics. Sometimes one of our basic assumptions bites us in the Gluteus Maximus. ;-)
The best we can do if you don't have a scope is play with a simulation and try to give you what we think are good values to try out. I plugged your circuit into the very good (and free) LTspice, and came up with the following values, which seemed to work well for me. I tried to achieve a 50% duty cycle. YMMV.
I am also including the source code so that you can paste it into an "*.asc" file and run it for yourself, and play with the simulation too. If you don't have an oscilloscope, LTspice is a close second, though you still have to learn how to make realistic simulations!
Finally, with this particular circuit, if both sides are too well-balanced, it can refuse to start up. If you're using 1% resistors, and the transistors are well-matched (unlikely), the startup problem can manifest itself. In trying to achieve a 50% duty cycle, my values are well-unbalanced, so to speak, and there shouldn't be a problem.
Here is my tweaked simulation of your circuit: (I did add some pull-down resistors to the transistor-bases, because I like my transistors to turn off more quickly).


Here is the LTspice Source Code for the above simulation: (LTspice XVII for Windows)

Version 4
SHEET 1 1460 680
WIRE -256 -192 -464 -192
WIRE 80 -192 -256 -192
WIRE 448 -192 80 -192
WIRE 512 -192 448 -192
WIRE 608 -192 576 -192
WIRE 656 -192 608 -192
WIRE 784 -192 736 -192
WIRE 1280 -192 784 -192
WIRE 80 -176 80 -192
WIRE 784 -96 784 -192
WIRE 848 -96 784 -96
WIRE 80 -64 80 -96
WIRE 176 -64 80 -64
WIRE 608 -64 608 -192
WIRE 608 -64 240 -64
WIRE 784 -64 784 -96
WIRE -464 -32 -464 -192
WIRE -256 0 -256 -192
WIRE 80 0 80 -64
WIRE 80 0 -64 0
WIRE 320 0 80 0
WIRE -64 16 -64 0
WIRE 320 16 320 0
WIRE 448 32 448 -192
WIRE 784 48 784 16
WIRE 848 48 784 48
WIRE 1280 64 1280 -192
WIRE 784 96 784 48
WIRE -256 112 -256 80
WIRE 32 112 -256 112
WIRE 320 112 320 96
WIRE 320 112 96 112
WIRE -64 160 -64 96
WIRE 160 160 -64 160
WIRE 448 160 448 112
WIRE 448 160 224 160
WIRE -256 192 -256 112
WIRE 448 192 448 160
WIRE -64 240 -64 160
WIRE -64 240 -192 240
WIRE 0 240 -64 240
WIRE 320 240 320 112
WIRE 320 240 256 240
WIRE 384 240 320 240
WIRE 784 240 784 176
WIRE 1280 240 1280 144
WIRE 0 256 0 240
WIRE 256 256 256 240
WIRE 672 288 448 288
WIRE 720 288 672 288
WIRE 576 320 512 320
WIRE 672 320 672 288
WIRE 672 320 656 320
WIRE -464 368 -464 32
WIRE -256 368 -256 288
WIRE -256 368 -464 368
WIRE 0 368 0 336
WIRE 0 368 -256 368
WIRE 256 368 256 336
WIRE 256 368 0 368
WIRE 512 368 512 320
WIRE 512 368 256 368
WIRE 784 368 784 336
WIRE 784 368 512 368
WIRE 784 400 784 368
WIRE 1280 400 1280 320
FLAG 1280 400 0
FLAG 784 400 0
FLAG 848 -96 R6
FLAG 848 48 R7
SYMBOL voltage 1280 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 9V
SYMBOL npn 384 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q2
SYMATTR Value BC337-40
SYMBOL npn -192 192 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value BC337-40
SYMBOL npn 720 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q3
SYMATTR Value BC337-40
SYMBOL cap 96 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 0.01µF
SYMBOL cap 224 144 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 0.01µF
SYMBOL res 304 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 33K
SYMBOL res -48 0 M0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 22K
SYMBOL res 432 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2K2
SYMBOL res -240 -16 M0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 4K7
SYMBOL res 64 -192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 50K
SYMBOL diode 576 -208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL diode 240 -80 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL res 768 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 8
SYMBOL res 768 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 68
SYMBOL res 752 -208 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName SW1
SYMATTR Value 100m
SYMBOL cap -480 -32 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 33µF
SYMBOL res 1264 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 25
SYMBOL res -16 240 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res 272 240 M0
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 100K
SYMBOL res 672 304 R90
WINDOW 0 51 103 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 27 4 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10K
TEXT -232 384 Left 2 ;Fresh 9V batteries have low DC resistance, 5 to 25 ohms depending on construction
TEXT 872 -24 Left 2 ;Speaker
TEXT 902 412 Left 2 !.tran 0 40m 10m startup
TEXT 832 -176 Left 2 ;~ 2.5 KHz  \nBuzzer Sound
TEXT 888 8 Left 2 ;26.73mW
TEXT 1224 -32 Left 2 ;9V Battery\ninternal\nResistance
RECTANGLE Normal 1008 80 736 -128 2
RECTANGLE Normal 1408 368 1136 -96 2
RECTANGLE Normal 1360 176 1184 -64 2


The idea with the oscillator circuit is that it has loop gain >1 at the frequency of oscillation, and it amplifies its own noise. It will always start. SPICE simulations that don't add that noise won't capture this behavior. Of course, the bias has to be set such that this loop gain is where you want it. Usually the values are all wrong. The transistors cannot be saturated for this to work.

Except your circuit has 7 transistors, and this one has only two. I think that I trust Nuts and Volts magazine to give me a "sure start" circuit. Have you even looked at it?
